# how to list a name n-times?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas data frame named `df` and an integer variable named `n`.

how can I create a list of `n`-times my dataframe's name `df`?

Example:

```
n=3
l = [df,df,df]
```

Note: `n` changes almost randomly for every execution.

Comment: Remember that listing n times puts *the same object* in the list, so changing one will change all the others. You might want to read about [how to make copies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) instead and define what you need. One option could be `l = [df.copy(deep=True) for _ in range(n)]`.

Comment: @yatu those two are still the same, arent they?

Comment: Not entirely, on the first each item in the list points to the same object, so changes are reflected across all of them, whereas with the second we're just creating n copies @quang

Comment: @yatu But then `df` is a pointer, so all of the elements are pointing to the same object still.

Comment: Ha! You're exactly right @quang, I mixed up concepts there :)

Comment: Possibly `l = [df.copy() for _ in range(n)]` is the most advisable then @quang

Comment: @Guimoute: Thanx! I do want to have the same object n-times and it to be updated everywhere if a change happens. The comment is still relevant for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to replicate the list `n` times:

```
l = [df for _ in range(n)]
```

Though note that, as mentioned in the comments, this creates `n` references to the same object, so a change in any of them will be reflected across all dataframes. If that is a problem (which most likely is) take a new `copy` on each iteration:

```
l = [df.copy() for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: poor answer, list comprehension is always faster.

Comment: A list comp is a nice and simpler way to express just this :)

Comment: Not necessarily @bernie But they are more idiomatic in these simple cases

Comment: A very basic answer.

Comment: No problem, just saw your comment by accident, its yatu, not yahoo :)

Comment: @yatu You noticed XD

Comment: eehm... how does the list-comprehension-answer looks like? and how does the non-list-comprehension-answer looks like?

Comment: @scjorge You can see the initial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62052378/revisions) in the revisions :)